# Merge multiple files on aws s3 into zip

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an application which uploads a lot of audio files to AWS S3. Is that possible to zip arbitrary files on the server on the fly and let the user download entire archive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but you would have to write all the code. There are two general ways to do it:

**1. Via Amazon EC2 web server**

Create a web server on Amazon EC2 using your preferred operating system, web server, etc. Write a web app that does what you desire.

**2. Via AWS Lambda and Amazon API Gateway**

The new-fangled world is to avoid servers by writing code for [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html), which is an event-activated service that runs code you provide. Combine it [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) to handle requests as API calls and you don't need a server.

There's even new frameworks such as **[JAWS](https://github.com/jaws-stack/JAWS) (JavaScript + AWS Stack)** that makes this easier:

[image: JAWS]